# unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Tags: php, parent

I try to parent a function but I get this error:

```
unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

I have PHP v5.4.7
Here is code

```
public function static tableExist($table, $db)
    {
        $tables = mysql_exists($db);
            while(list($temp) = mysql_fetch_array($name, $pass))
            {
                if($temp = $table)
                {
                    return TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }

    }
```

and the usage

```
if(register::tableExist(users, webshop));
                {
                    echo "succes";
                }
```

Comment: `public static function`

Comment: You may wish to reference [the PHP manual on OOP](http://php.net/language.oop5) for future syntax questions.

Comment: I removed the OOP tag, because when you start using `static`s it's really not that OOP. Just because you are using classes doesn't make it OOP.

Answer (score 1):

try `public static function tableExist`

EDIT: do you have a specific line reference?

Comment: public function static tableExist($table, $db)

Comment: Then as above, `public static function` is what you want.

Comment: @Hangslotman This is the suitable answer. you have mistaken in defining your method.

Comment: @Neurenor, do you have a question?

Comment: Maybe you should post your own question?